# Is calling a method considered a relationship on a class diagram?

Tags: modeling, class-diagram

I'd like to know if calling a method from a different class is considered a relationship on a class diagram.
Regards.

Comment: If class `A` uses a / has a member of class `B`, then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always.    Some types of relationships (e.g. a uses b, a notifies b, etc) can be implemented or supported by calling of an object's method thoough.

It depends on how closely the class diagram represents relationships.  That is a design choice.